# Need to parse an xml file and construct an excel workbook

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I need to parse an XML file and then prepare a workbook with a particular format. To create the columns in the excel sheet I am using a YAML file. The YAML file looks like this,

```
Sheet1:
    1:
        - Country Name: ./country@name #this should be a unique value
        - Description: ./country@descr
        - Neighbor: ./country/neighbor@name
    2:
        - Country Name: ./country@name #this should be a unique value
        - Year: ./country@year
```

XML Data:

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein" descr="TT">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama" desc="RR">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Moving onto the subject:
I tried to parse the xml data and then create a Dataframe out of it. This data frame will be written to the excel workbook.
I used the values from the YAML file as an input to the findall(./country) and .get(name) methods from ElementTree.
Things work fine when I have an equal number of neighbor data in the example. But I don't. I am currently populating the column data as a list. I know this is wrong. I want to know if there is a better way to insert NaN/None as shown below,

This is what I get,

```
Sheet1
    Country Name Description     Neighbor
0  Liechtenstein          TT      Austria
1      Singapore        None  Switzerland
2         Panama        None     Malaysia
3            NaN         NaN   Costa Rica
4            NaN         NaN     Colombia
```

This is what I need

```
Sheet1
    Country Name Description     Neighbor
0  Liechtenstein          TT        Austria
1. Liechtenstein          TT    Switzerland
1      Singapore        None       Malaysia
2         Panama        None     Costa Rica
3         Panama        None       Colombia
```

EDIT: The YAML file can have more column names and this needs to be dynamically fed into the excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to get your data into a dataframe, and you can take it from there:

```
import pandas as pd
import lxml.html as lh
countries = """[your html above - fixed (a closing " is missing in the first descr value)]"""

doc = lh.fromstring(countries)
rows = []
cols = ["Country Name", "Description",  "Neighbor"]
for country in doc.xpath('//country'):    
    for neighbor in country.xpath('.//neighbor/@name'):
        row = []
        row.append(country.xpath('@name')[0])
        if len(country.xpath('@descr'))>0:
            row.append(country.xpath('@descr')[0])
        else:
            row.append("None")
        row.append(neighbor)
        rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

Output:

```
   Country Name Description Neighbor
0   Liechtenstein   TT  Austria
1   Liechtenstein   TT  Switzerland
2   Singapore      None     Malaysia
3   Panama        None  Costa Rica
4   Panama       None   Colombia
```